# Error: Invalid configuration of route '': Array cannot be specified

Tags: angularjs, typescript

i came through this error while running angular, can any one help me to figure this out..
my **app.module.ts** file is

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';
import { RecipesComponent } from './recipes/recipes.component';    
import { RecipesListComponent } from './recipes/recipes-list/recipes-list.component';
import { RecipesItemComponent } from './recipes/recipes-list/recipes-item.component';
import { RecipesDetailComponent } from './recipes/recipes-detail/recipes-detail.component';
import { UserdropdownDirectiveDirective } from './userdropdown-directive.directive';
import { ShoppingListComponent } from './shopping-list/shopping-list.component';
import { RecipeServiceService } from './recipes/recipe-service.service'
import { ShoppingServiceService } from './shopping-list/shopping-service.service';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import { routing } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        RecipesComponent,
        RecipesListComponent,
        RecipesItemComponent,
        RecipesDetailComponent,
        UserdropdownDirectiveDirective,
        ShoppingListComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule,
        routing
    ],
    providers: [RecipeServiceService, ShoppingServiceService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**app.router.ts** file is

```
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router"
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { provideRoutes } from "@angular/router";
import { RecipesComponent } from "./recipes/recipes.component";
import { ShoppingListComponent } from "./shopping-list/shopping-list.component";

export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/recipes', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'recipes', component:RecipesComponent },
    { path: 'shopping-list', component: ShoppingListComponent }
];

export const APP_ROUTES_PROVIDERS=[
    provideRoutes(APP_ROUTES)
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES_PROVIDERS);
```

Answer (score 0):

first, FORMAT your code, it's impossible to read... and try a routing component like this, without quote :

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'recipes', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'recipes', component:RecipesComponent },`
  { path: 'shopping-list', component: ShoppingListComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, { useHash: true })
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

i get it now, i have to update my ap.routes.ts class by the following code below

```
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router"
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { provideRoutes } from "@angular/router";
import { RecipesComponent } from "./recipes/recipes.component";
import { ShoppingListComponent } from "./shopping-list/shopping-list.component";
 export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
 {path: '', redirectTo: '/recipes', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'recipes', component:RecipesComponent },
 { path: 'shopping-list', component: ShoppingListComponent }];

 export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, { useHash: true })
```

All i have to do is to remove portion of code that is given below

```
   export const APP_ROUTES_PROVIDERS=[
 provideRoutes(APP_ROUTES)
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the `APP_ROUTE_PROVIDER`, you can let the file be as it was, just add the `APP_ROUTE_PROVIDERS` to the providers list in `app.module.ts` file. Code should have worked.

```
@NgModule({
....
    providers: [APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER,...]
..
})
```